# Seperate each word into seperate span

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of strings that I am displaying in HTML in `spans`. All spans are wrapped inside the `conteneditable` div. Now if a user is adding new words then the browser by default is adding that in the nearest span instead of creating a new span for each word.

Basically, I am running `*ngFor` to display `span` tags. I am updating the array so that it should also update the dom but here the issue is updated array is not getting displayed in HTML.

**HTML Code**

```xhtml
<div contenteditable="true" [id]="'data-section'+i">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let word of captionData.caption; trackBy:identify; let j = index">
    <span #caption [innerHTML]="word | punctuation" [id]="+i+'-'+j"></span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**TS Code**

```ts
seperateSpans(event: any, index: any) {

  const html: any = document.getElementById('data-section' + index)!;
  let spans = html.getElementsByTagName("span")!;
  let newArray: any = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    let innerTextSpan: any = spans[i]?.innerHTML.trim().split(/\s+/);
    // If span has multiple words, then push the words individually
    if (innerTextSpan.length > 1) {
      for (let j = 0; j < innerTextSpan.length; j++) {
        spans[i].innerHTML = innerTextSpan[j]
        newArray.push(innerTextSpan[j])
      }
    } else {
      newArray.push(innerTextSpan[0])
    }
  }

  this.captionListData[index].caption = newArray; // Assign the new array to current array so that the current HTML dom also should be refresh with new spans
}
```

Below is the initial text. Each word is in a new span

The initial text:

[image: Initial text]

Below is the image after adding new words and calling the mentioned function. The added words are coming twice

After adding new words:

[image: After adding new words]

As you can see in the above image, instead of each word getting binded with a span, the older spans remain there and with that new spans are also displaying, causing this duplicate. I don't know how to handle this.

**Goal:**
My end goal is to separate each word into a new span.
For example if there is 2 words in a span `<span>Demo text</span>`
After function call it should be `<span>Demo</span><span>text</span>`
Please let me know if I am missing anything here or if I should try any other approach

Comment: Please post [code/text instead of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Already posted the html and ts code.

Comment: Sure but not your output texts

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code is replacing span with a few words with the last word, not the first.

You need to change

```
spans[i].innerHTML = innerTextSpan[j]
```

to

```
spans[i].innerHTML = innerTextSpan[0]
```

and move it from the loop.

Should be something like this:

```
if (innerTextSpan.length > 1) {
    spans[i].innerHTML = innerTextSpan[0];
    for (let j = 0; j < innerTextSpan.length; j++) {
      newArray.push(innerTextSpan[j])
    }
  }
```

I tested it with simplified version of your html, works like a charm:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="data-section">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let word of captionListData">
    <span [innerHTML]="word"></span>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And inside ts function changed: `this.captionListData = newArray;`